Vias between power planes and power islands
In a PCB I am designing, on the top layer I generate 5V and 0.5V, and I made two individual layers that act as power planes for those voltages. The connection between the power planes and the two buck converters that generate the voltages occurs with two buried vias at a single point, at the output of the two ICs.
I was wondering if, similarly to what we do with ground planes and stitching vias, there was some best practice to improve this connection, such as making a power island on top layer as big as possible, and filling it with blind vias to the power planes of interest.
My anxiety suggests me that a single point of contact would be bad, but I have no technical basis for this statement so it may be just fine.
To give an idea of the distance between power generation and where it is used, here a sketch of the board for the 5V (the 1.5V is analogous)

Thanks!

What is your reason for using buried and blind vias? Do you understand that a through via can be used to connect any combination of layers (we do sometimes get questions from beginners who don't know this)?

I am absolutely a beginner, and as such I did not know this; I just used them because it seemed the most conservative way to go from A to B, but if there is some other downside to them I'm happy to learn

I mean, I knew through vias could connect selected layers, but I did not think to use them as overcomplete blind vias

@FrancescoBernardini Blind vias are not a conservative solution; the moment you include a blind or buried via on your board, the price to get the board made skyrockets. Blind and buried vias should always be avoided if possible.

understood! I was totally clueless about manufacturing costs


similarly to what we do with ground planes and stitching vias,

The reason for stitching vias is to ensure that two copper regions (on two layers) that are nominally the same circuit node don't develop a potential difference between them.

I was wondering if, ... there was some best practice to improve this connection [between the power regulator and the power plane]

If you don't have large overlapping regions of the same node, there is no need for stitching vias.

... such as making a power island on top layer as big as possible, and filling it with blind vias to the power planes of interest.

You may want to use multiple parallel vias between the regulator output and the power plane to reduce the resistance and inductance of the connection from the regulator to the plane.
There is no reason to prefer blind vias for this connection. Through vias will work just fine and cost less.

Thank you, I have updated the initial post with a sketch of the layout: would it still be of any help if the multiple parallel vias need to be confined in the power region?

and thanks for the tip about the vias! I'm definitely updating all of them

@FrancescoBernardini I'd use 2-3 vias no matter what (because vias are a common point of failure). More than that if the current draw is above 100 mA. Above 1 A I'd start calculating via resistance and actually doing engineering to decide how many vias are needed.

got u, current should be way lower than that, but I'll keep that in mind for the future; thanks!
